# How to extend JWTAuthentication in django- rest-framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I created CustomAuthentication class, this class extend JWTAuthentication class. I put this class in file auth.py and same location with settings.py.

in settings.py i modify:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {

'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (

'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',

),

'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (

'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',

),

}
```

to

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {

'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (

'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',

),

'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (

auth.CustomAuthentication',

),

}
```

But it it doest not work, it throws

"Could not import 'auth.CustomAuthentication' for API setting 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES'. ImportError: Module "auth" does not define a "CustomAuthentication" attribute/class."

Here is content of auth.py:

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication import JWTAuthentication
class CustomJWTAuthentication(JWTAuthentication):
    is_valid = True
```

What is wrong here? please help.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you imported the auth.py file in settings.py?

Comment: try 'appname.auth.CustomAuthentication' where appname is the name of your app.

Comment: @HeisAif: how to mark the answer as accepted?

Comment: click on the check mark on the left side of the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in with green colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class name is 'CustomJWTAuthentication' in auth.py and you are using 'CustomAuthentication' in settings.py, change it so both are same.